# Disable VPN for certain programs

Tags: windows-7, networking, vpn

I need to have a VPN connection open for a customer I work for. While working I like to listen to some online radio. When the VPN connection is open all of my traffic is being routed through the servers of my customer. I would like to tell my browser, that it should use my default internet connection instead of the VPN. I know that ForceBindIP exists but it seems to not work with Windows 7 64Bit.

Any ideas?

Comment: Based on the described situation, due to the way the VPN server is configured, you won't be able to do what you want.

Comment: :-( I thought of that but wanted to make sure. Thanks!

Comment: We acme up with a new idea: We install a VirtualBox which is used to connect to the VPN and work for the customer. Everything else will be on my local machine.